# Convert xml to json in javascript or d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xml-parsing

I am using d3.xml to parse xml data but it returns document object. So how do I convert xml data to json using javascript or d3.js.

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/

Comment: Hey Dawid thank you, but i need a javascript function which converts xml to json. So that i can convert data inside my code and use it directly in d3.js to create visualizations